# MSapriori and CARapriori algorithm implementations in Python or R

Tags: r, python-3.x, apriori

MSapriori and CARapriori are particular versions of the apriori algorithm for finding association rules in say a dataset of transactions (basket analysis).

MSapriori sets different minum support requirements for different items.

CARapriori is finding associations with a specific target in mind.

My question is if you know of implementations of these algorithms in Python or R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the `arules` package in `R`? You can set minimum support requirement in the options as well as set a target. Here's an example straight out of the documentation:

```
library("arules")
data("Adult")
rules <- apriori(Adult, parameter = list(supp = 0.5, conf = 0.9, target = "rules"))
```

Here's a link that might help you as well: [How to find the minimum support in Apriori algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364632/how-to-find-the-minimum-support-in-apriori-algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

The R package `arulesCBA` has a function called `mineCARs` to mine classification association rules, i.e., rules with items for classification in the RHS. The following example is taken from the manual page.

```
data("iris")

iris.disc <- discretizeDF.supervised(Species ~ ., iris)
iris.trans <- as(iris.disc, "transactions")

# mine CARs with items for "Species" in the RHS
cars <- mineCARs(Species ~ ., iris.trans, parameter = list(support = 0.3))
inspect(cars)
```

I don't think the R implementations support multiple minimum support at this time.